# Remove '||'(double pipe) separated multiple columns from file using shell script command

Tags: awk, grep, cut

Please suggest perfect shell script command to remove last two '||' delimiter separated columns from the file.(Lets assume below example)
**File Name: abc.dat**

```
"a1"||"a2"||"a3"||"a4"
"b1"||"b2"||"b3"||"b4"
"c1"||"c2"||"c3"||"c4"
```

output should be like :

```
"a1"||"a2"
"b1"||"b2"
"c1"||"c2"
```

I tried below cut and awk command but not worked:

```
awk -F '||' '{print $1$2}'  ${file} >> ${file}
cut -d'||' -f2 --complement ${file} >> ${file} (not working as cut: the delimiter must be a single character)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than assuming `||` is the delimiter, assume that `|` is the delimiter and the second field is empty.

```
$ cut -d'|' -f1-3 <<EOF
> "a1"||"a2"||"a3"||"a4"
> "b1"||"b2"||"b3"||"b4"
> "c1"||"c2"||"c3"||"c4"
> EOF
"a1"||"a2"
"b1"||"b2"
"c1"||"c2"
```

(This assumes that `||` was chosen for some aesthetic reason, rather than to allow for single pipes in each field.)

Comment: If there are `|` characters in between the `||`s then it may not work

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I acknowledge that in the last sentence.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following. Make field separator as `||`(escaping it to treat literal character) along with setting OFS to `||` too. Then print 1st and 2nd fields for each line of Input_file.

```
awk -F'\\|\\|' -v OFS="||" '{print $1,$2}' Input_file
```

Once you are happy with results of above command, also to make changes into Input_file itself try following.

```
awk -F'\\|\\|' -v OFS="||" '{print $1,$2}' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` try following.

```
grep -oP '^.*?\|\|"[^"]*' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for your reply, 
your solution is working nicely, Only 1 thing, I am getting extra '||' at the last using 1st solution.

Comment: @R_Kalavadiya, with your shown samples these solutions worked fine for me.

Comment: @R_Kalavadiya [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471662/remove-double-pipe-separated-multiple-columns-from-file-using-shell-script#comment119257480_67471702) is impossible given the input you show and the script in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```sh
awk '{sub(/(\|{2}[^|]*){2}$/, "")} 1' file

"a1"||"a2"
"b1"||"b2"
"c1"||"c2"
```

Or if you just want to remove last 2 columns without caring how many columns are there in total use:

```sh
awk -F '\\|{2}' -v OFS='||' '{
   $NF = $(NF-1) = ""
   sub(/([|]{2})*$/, "")
} 1' file
```